# Flutter: Decoding Json if type of object is unknown

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I've three entity classes. For example an abstract animal class, a cat and a dog class, which extend the animal class. The dog and cat class both have a toJson() and fromJson() method.
I'm reading a file from the file system. Then I'm using the jsonDecode method on the String.
Next step would be calling the fromJson() mehthod on the result of the jsonDecode() method.

But here is the problem:
It could be a dog or a cat. So how am I supposed to know, which fromJson() method I should call?

```
String content = file.readAsStringSync();
Cat.fromJson(jsonDecode(content)); //it could be a dog
```

Comment: Do you not have that information on the JSON String? Instead of passing the data directly into your class, parse it first, check if it's a Dog, Cat or something else, and only then instantiate the appropriate Class

Comment: Yep, that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pascal! Is there something different about the strings ? How do you save'em ? Maybe you should add a "type" or something indicating if it's a Dog or a Cat to your toJson method and then parse the string by it.

Comment: Thanks :)   Both classes have a specific attribute. I could use this attribute to decide of which type the object is.